# Get Raspberry Pi Camera Feed into Darknet and Yolo

Tags: python, ubuntu, machine-learning, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I'm trying to feed my Raspberry Pi MPEG Video stream into a Ubuntu machine learning system called [Darknet](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/).

Darknet runs properly now on its sample images, so it's running fine there. My Pi transmits a constant JPG stream to the local URL http://192.168.1.xx. However, whenever I run the darknet command to do basic recognition on this stream, all I get is a black image result.

Here's the command as I see it:

```
./darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolo.cfg yolo.weights http://192.168.1.xx/cam.jpg
```

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be old but just in case anyone else has the same problem, the "test" option is for images and "demo" is for videos, so try using "demo" instead so your command will be :

```
   ./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolo.cfg yolo.weights http://192.168.1.xx/cam.jpg
```